# How do I convert all the values of a dataframe in Pandas (not just one column rather of whole dataset) from 'y' to 1 and 'n' to 0?

Tags: python, pandas

```
    party   infants     water   budget  physician   salvador    religious   satellite   aid     missile     immigration     synfuels    education   superfund   crime   duty_free_exports   eaa_rsa
0   republican  n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n   n   y   NaN     y   y   y   n   y
1   republican  n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n   n   n   n   y   y   y   n   NaN
2   democrat    NaN     y   y   NaN     y   y   n   n   n   n   y   n   y   y   n   n
3   democrat    n   y   y   n   NaN     y   n   n   n   n   y   n   y   n   n   y
4   democrat    y   y   y   n   y   y   n   n   n   n   y   NaN     y   y
```

This is the head of my dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the values on the entire datframe

```
df = df.replace(['y','n'],[1,0])
```